# How to read and print random rows from Excel file in Python?

Tags: python, excel, random

I'm trying to create a script that will output random rows from an Excel file. Essentially, this would be like flashcards for studying. I want random rows of data to output one at a time. What I have so far is below; I know I'm off and need some help.

```
import xlrd
import random
loc = ("FILE PATH")

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

sheet.cell_value(0,0)

for i in range(sheet)
    print(random.sheet.row_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with something like this and edit it as needed.

```
import xlrd 
import random 

# path to file:
path_to_file = "path/to/spreadsheet.xlsx"

# get, set workbook, sheet:
work_book = xlrd.open_workbook(path_to_file) 
sheet = work_book.sheet_by_index(0)

# infinite loop:
while True:

    # ask user to continue:
    input('Print next row?: ')

    # get a random index between 0 and total number of rows:
    random_index = random.randrange(0, sheet.nrows)

    # print row:
    print(sheet.row(random_index))
```