# How to print random rows from xslx file with python openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

is there any way to print random rows from xlsx file with openpyxl? I am still a python beginner, so I have no idea how. I've tried to look it up on google but the only way to do that is with xlrd. Unfortunately, xlrd doesn't support xslx anymore.

[How to read and print random rows from Excel file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60106910/how-to-read-and-print-random-rows-from-excel-file-in-python)
This is the link that i meant and I wanted to do the exact same thing but with openpyxl

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). This site is best used once you have a specific problem that you can't figure out around code that you are writing. Your question, reads like "Can someone code this for me" or "Can someone point me towards a tutorial or information on how to code this" which are off-topic. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to print random rows from an excel sheet using openpyxl

```
import openpyxl
import random
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('Sample.xlsx') ## Read excel
ws=wb['Sheet1']  ## Sheet to read
len = ws.max_row ## read the number of rows in that sheet
breakout = False ## Use to break out of both loop - to exit
while True:
    randrow = random.randint(1, len)  ## Get random number between 1 - len of sheet
    for row in ws.iter_rows(randrow, randrow): ## Read the row
        print('Row number : ', randrow)   ## Print row number
        print([cell.value for cell in row])  ## Print row contents
        Cont = input('Continue? (y/n):')  ## As if user wants to continue/exit
        if Cont.upper() == 'N':  ## If N/n, exit
            breakout = True  
            break  ## Break out of for loop
    if breakout==True:
        break  ## Break out of While loop and exit
```